# Angular Http Post in Safari Hitting Different url than Chrome

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, http, safari

I'm using angulars and the built in $http directive to post to our API end point. It works in Chrome but I am having an issue in Safari. Here's the call from my Api factory:

```js
assignments: function(csv) {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $http({
     method: 'POST',
     url: '/api/numbers/assignments',
     data: $.param({
       skipBillables: false,
       assignments: csv,
     }),
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
     }
   }).success(function(data) {
     deferred.resolve(data);
   }).error(function(data) {
     deferred.reject(data);
   })
   return deferred.promise;
 },
```

Now my controllers consumes Api.assignments that I created. Here's the following snippet:

```js
Api.updateSubscription(org.id, cardData).then(function(data) {
   
   Api.getSession().then(function(data) {
     
     if (!_($scope.savedTollFreeNumberCheckout).isBlank()) {

       var checkouttollfreenumber = '1' + $scope.savedTollFreeNumberCheckout.tfn;
       var assignObj = [{
         phoneNum: checkouttollfreenumber,
         email: owner.emailAddress,
         percent: 0,
       }];
       var csvFile = downloadCSV(assignObj);
       console.log(csvFile);
       Api.assignments(csvFile).then(function(data) {
         $window.location.reload();
       });

     };
   });
 });
```

When I call this, it works in Chrome. The only browser that it is not working is Safari. In Safari, the full URL that is being called is: http://local.appname.com:9000/18775078169,useremai@email.com,percentageparameter, which is not the correct endpoint. In Chrome it is hitting http://local.appname.com:9000/api/numbers/assignments If anyone has any suggestions on a fix, I would really appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think you need to have $.params if you are planning to send the data as a json object with the post request.

$.param is mainly to serialize the params for query params.

```
    assignments: function(csv) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/numbers/assignments',
        data: {
          skipBillables: false,
          assignments: csv,
        },
        headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
       }).success(function(data) {
         deferred.resolve(data);
       }).error(function(data) {
         deferred.reject(data);
       })
       return deferred.promise;
    },
```

you should do this or if you really want to send the data as queryparams

```
   assignments: function(csv) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/numbers/assignments'+'?'+$.params({ skipBillables: false,assignments: csv}),
        headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
       }).success(function(data) {
         deferred.resolve(data);
       }).error(function(data) {
         deferred.reject(data);
       })
       return deferred.promise;
    },
```

But as good practice to send data

Get Requests - use query Params

Post Requests - use json

Comment: Also $.param is used for POST if data is expected to be sent as `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for why the post seems to work in chrome but not safari? Appreciate the help.